# How to detect XOFF and XON in Linux terminal application

Tags: c++, linux, signals

Certain control sequences have special effects in Linux, such as `CTRL-C` which sends `SIGINT`. I can handle signals easily enough, but it appears `CTRL-S` (XOFF) and `CTRL-Q` (XON) are special snowflakes. I know their effect (to pause input) can be disabled in the console with `stty -ixon`, and I could use some trickery to run that command, but that feels like a cheap workaround.

Is there a proper way to rid these sequences of their special effect and get their actual ASCII values (`^S`, `^Q`) using system calls? I know it is doable because the text editor Nano does it, but for the life of me I can't find where it's being handled. I already tried searching the repo for "XOFF".

https://github.com/dtrebbien/nano/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [tcgetattr() and tcsetattr() system calls](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/termios.3.html) to turn off the `IXON` flag on standard input, as explained in this manual page.